# pypy memory usage grows forever?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks, pypy

I have a complicated python server app, that runs constantly all the time.  Below is a very simplified version of it.

When I run the below app using python; "python Main.py".  It uses 8mb of ram straight away, and stays at 8mb of ram, as it should.

When I run it using pypy "pypy Main.py".  It begins by using 22mb of ram and over time the ram usage grows. After a 30 seconds its at 50mb, after an hour its at 60mb.

If I change the "b.something()" to be "pass" it doesn't gobble up memory like that.

I'm using pypy 1.9 on OSX 10.7.4
I'm okay with pypy using more ram than python.

**Is there a way to stop pypy from eating up memory over long periods of time?**

```
import sys
import time
import traceback

class Box(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def something(self):
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter > 100:
            self.counter = 0

try:
    print 'starting...'
    boxes = []      
    for i in range(10000):
        boxes.append(Box())
    print 'running!'
    while True:
        for b in boxes:
            b.something()
        time.sleep(0.02)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ''
    print '####################################'
    print 'KeyboardInterrupt Exception'
    sys.exit(1)

except Exception as e:
    print ''
    print '####################################'
    print 'Main Level Exception: %s' % e
    print traceback.format_exc()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Below is a list of times and the ram usage at that time (I left it running over night).

```
Wed Sep  5 22:57:54 2012, 22mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:57:54 2012, 23mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:57:56 2012, 24mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:57:56 2012, 25mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:57:58 2012, 26mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:57:58 2012, 27mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:57:59 2012, 29mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:57:59 2012, 30mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:00 2012, 31mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:02 2012, 32mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:03 2012, 33mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:05 2012, 34mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:08 2012, 35mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:10 2012, 36mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:12 2012, 38mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:13 2012, 39mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:16 2012, 40mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:19 2012, 41mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:21 2012, 42mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:23 2012, 43mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:26 2012, 44mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:28 2012, 45mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:31 2012, 46mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:33 2012, 47mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:35 2012, 49mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:35 2012, 50mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:36 2012, 51mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:36 2012, 52mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:58:37 2012, 54mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:59:41 2012, 55mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:59:45 2012, 56mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 22:59:45 2012, 57mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 23:00:58 2012, 58mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 23:02:20 2012, 59mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 23:02:20 2012, 60mb ram 
Wed Sep  5 23:02:27 2012, 61mb ram 
Thu Sep  6 00:18:00 2012, 62mb ram
```

Comment: Hmm.  I can't reproduce this.  With pypy 1.9 (from Macports) and OS X 10.6.8, I see the memory usage (as reported by 'top', from the RSIZE column) stay at around 46M.  It may be worth a bug report.

Comment: I've still got that process running, new data point for it:
Thu Sep  6 09:02:26 2012, 63mb ram

Comment: I can reproduce this using pypy 1.8, but 1.9 seems to have corrected this problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/gc_info.html#minimark-environment-variables shows how to tweak the gc

Comment: Oops, commented on the wrong reply, moved my comment to the above answer.

Comment: 4 months later and i've realized that what Ronny linked to is an even better solution.   Setting PYPY_GC_MIN=1GB and PYPY_GC_MAX=3GB works much better, keeping the ram usage between 1 and 3 gb.   And I found that the gc.collect() calls were taking around 50ms... slowing my application down too much.  So yeah, those environment variables are a much better way to go. :)

Comment: @DavidColquhoun that's `PYPY_GC_MIN=1GB` and `PYPY_GC_MAX=3GB`, not `PYPY_GC_MIN="1GB"` and `PYPY_GC_MAX="3GB"`, correct?

Comment: both should work the same, quoting is needed  only when separators or whitespace are used for a shell, foo and "foo" tend to be the same

Comment: I found my side set up, but it's not working. What's the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Compared to cpython, pypy uses [different garbage collection strategies](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html#differences-related-to-garbage-collection-strategies).
If the increase in memory is due to something in your program, you could try to run a forced garbage collection every now and then, by using the [`collect`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html?highlight=gc#gc.collect) function from the `gc` module. In this case, it might also help to explicitly `del` large objects that you don't need anymore and that don't go out of scope.

If it is due to the internal workings of pypy, it might be worth it submitting a bug report, as Mark Dickinson suggested.

Comment: Thankyou! gc.collect() was the what I needed.  I run that every few seconds and it keeps the memory usage flat...  check out the graph here to see the difference that one command made: http://datasmugglers.com/2012/10/06/server-ram-usage/